# What is the name of the song that plays following "Sweetie, you and me are going to make the baby?"

Tags: soundtrack, family-guy

In the film [Stewie Griffin: The Untold Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewie_Griffin:_The_Untold_Story), there is a scene in which we see Stewie Griffin ruminate about where babies come from.  In Stewie's imagination, a giant stork flies into a window and tells an expectant mom, "You and me are going to make the baby." after which the first five seconds of a song plays.

What is the name of the song?

**Edit**: I see that someone has posted this on YouTube:

Comment: Is that all the music that is heard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that is really from an actual song. Rather than that, it is supposed to be the classic stereotypical funky-style "porn music" to imply that the stork and the woman are indeed about to make that baby right now, as also implied by the red light the stork installs and his whole behaviour.

This kind of cliché "porn music" is a common trope often used in a comedic way to signal that something sexual is going on or about to happen, like in this scene. A variation of this trope is when characters utter the words [*"bow chicka wow wow"*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bow%20chicka%20wow%20wow) in a melodic way in order to immitate this funky music and in turn imply something sexual in a funny or satirical way.

I'm not sure how extensive [this Family Guy wiki page](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Stewie_Griffin%3a_The_Untold_Story) is and I have only checked it roughly, but it doesn't seem to list the song explicitly as reference or music used in the episode/movie.

Comment: I could have sworn I heard that song on the radio the other day ;-)

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Updated the answer a bit.

Answer (score -1):

HERE IT IS WHERE ITS FROM, AFTER ALMOST A DECADE !!!! 3:40 starts the "song"

Comment: 5 years is not "almost a decade"

Comment: And that doesn't sound at all like the same song to me.